# Javascript date validation allowing wrong characters

Tags: javascript, validation, date

For some reason, my date validation allows fullstops to be passed, but only at the end of that part of the date, e.g. 12./10/201 gets passed but 1.2/10/201 doesn't.

Here is my code:

```
var iDate = $("check_date").value;

  if(iDate.length > 0) {
    var a = iDate.split("/"); 
    if(isValidDate(a[0],a[1]-1,a[2]) == false){
      alert("You have entered an invalid date.");
      return false;
    }

isValidDate = function(day,month,year) {
  var dteDate;
  dteDate=new Date(year,month,day);
  return ((day==dteDate.getDate()) && (month==dteDate.getMonth()) && (year==dteDate.getFullYear()));
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, I'd say that 12. is interpreted by JavaScript as 12, so it's comparing 12 and 12, but 1.2 compared to 12 is not equal (it's comparing them as integers). I'd say do a .toString() and compare the strings. That's just my wild guess :) Or just try to use three equals (===) to make a strict compare.

Comment: And is the resulting date stored on dteDate the correct one? Or just a valid date?

Comment: -1 is right in this case, for the months, JavaScript starts at 0

Comment: @jValdron thanks buddy i was just asking!

Comment: The weird thing is 12/10/201. also gets passed, and if you do similar with the month. @Deleteman The resulting date is whatever it accepts, so it'll accept 12./10/201 for example.

Comment: Same thing, if you compare `201.` to `201`, it's actually valid. When you pass `201.` to the Date object, it interprets it as `201`. So it creates a date with 201 as the year. When you go and compare 201 to 201. it compares it as integers, which means you'd have to compare the strings for all 3 of 'em.

Comment: @jValdron I added another equals sign and that seems to have done the trick, shame I can't mark you as the answer.

Comment: @Alias You can now ;) Haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, here is the solution:

```
isValidDate = function(day,month,year) {
    var dteDate;
    dteDate=new Date(year,month,day);
    return ((day.toString()===dteDate.getDate().toString()) && (month.toString()===dteDate.getMonth().toString()) && (year.toString()===dteDate.getFullYear().toString()));
}
```

You also need the toString() methods, as if you compare `"12"` and `12`, it won't be equal. Now you'll compare `"12"` with `"12"` which will be equal for valid dates.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function to check if the date is valid. Take a look at this code:

```
function isDate(dateStr) {
    var datePat = /^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{4})$/;
    var matchArray = dateStr.match(datePat); // is the format ok?

    if (matchArray == null) {
        alert("Please enter date as either mm/dd/yyyy or mm-dd-yyyy.");
        return false;
    }

    month = matchArray[1]; // p@rse date into variables
    day = matchArray[3];
    year = matchArray[5];

    if (month < 1 || month > 12) { // check month range
        alert("Month must be between 1 and 12.");
        return false;
    }

    if (day < 1 || day > 31) {
        alert("Day must be between 1 and 31.");
        return false;
    }

    if ((month==4 || month==6 || month==9 || month==11) && day==31) {
        alert("Month "+month+" doesn`t have 31 days!")
        return false;
    }

    if (month == 2) { // check for february 29th
        var isleap = (year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0));
        if (day > 29 || (day==29 && !isleap)) {
            alert("February " + year + " doesn`t have " + day + " days!");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true; // date is valid
}
```

Comment: The answer is good. However, it's much better to help others with their current solutions so they can learn. Anyone can Google for a function to validate dates :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because `"12."` is interpreted as `12`, when parsing the string to a number (This happens internally, in the date object).
Try this:

```
if(isValidDate(a[0],a[1]-1,a[2]) == false && iDate.indexOf('.') == -1){
```

Basically, just check for the dot.

Answer (score 0):

1. is valid number. After it is passed to the Date constructor it translated to Number as 12.0 and it obviously equals to 12. 1.2 is not. I'd recommend you to match the regexp first and then check the correctness of the parts as you did.

I would suggest you to implement something like this:

```
function isValidDate(dateString)
{
    if(! dateString.match(/((1[0-2])|(0?\d))\/(([0-2]?\d)|(3[0-1]))/(\d\d)?\d\d/) )
        return false;

    var parts = dateString.split("/");
    var dateToCheck = new Date(parts[0],parts[1]-1,parts[2]);

    return ((parts[0]==dateToCheck.getDate()) && (parts[1]==dateToCheck.getMonth()+1) && (parts[2]==dateToCheck.getFullYear()));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm glad to be here

Answer (score 0):

This is my version of date validation. It will not allow to enter wrong date even some one intend to type. This will also auto populate / after month and day.

```
$("#date").keyup(function (e) {
                // validation for length max 10
                var temp = $(this).val();
                if (temp.length > 10) $(this).val(temp.substring(0, temp.length - 1));

                var key = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
                console.log(key + " " + e.keyCode);
                var regex = /[0-9]|[a-i]|\/|\`|\o|\¿|\%|\'|\$/;                            
                // checking teh allowed character
                if (!regex.test(key)) {
                    // checking backspace and shift key ( need to allow)
                    if (e.keyCode != 8 && e.keyCode != 16) {
                        var tam = $(this).val().length;
                        $(this).val(temp.substring(0, tam - 1));
                    }
                }
                else {
                    //if its not backslash
                    if (e.keyCode != 191 && e.keyCode != 111) {
                        if ($(this).val().length == 2) {
                            $(this).val($(this).val() + "/");
                        } else if ($(this).val().length == 5) {
                            $(this).val($(this).val() + "/");
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        // if backslash
                        if ($(this).val().length != 3 && $(this).val().length != 6) {
                            var tam = $(this).val().length;
                            $(this).val(temp.substring(0, tam - 1));
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```